# syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) its coming during using 'like clause (%) in query

Tags: php, html, sql

Getting Error while running this code , and this is related to when search key is coming in search filter its making pagination correct but after clicking second page its lost the content of search filter and start showing normal index pagination , May be this error is generation when i am using **like clause** in query-

```
if(isset($_POST['submitSearch'])){
    $_session['$search']=$_POST['search'];  
    $all_post_query= "select * from files where recieved_by like '% $_session["$search"]%' or processed_by like  '% $_session["$search"]%' or   purpose like  '% $_session["$search"]%' or file_name like  '% $_session["$search"]%' order by date desc";
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fileprogramsysteeem");
    $all_post_run=mysqli_query($con,$all_post_query);
    $all_post=mysqli_num_rows( $all_post_run);
    $total_page=ceil($all_post/$total_num_page);
    $page_start_from=($page_id-1)*$total_num_page;
}
```

Someone help me please , i am new in php

Comment: `$_session['$search']` is wrong . It need to be `$_SESSION`

Comment: do some basic Google before asking question on SO.

Comment: Also your code is vulnerable to SQL injection - you pass data from request directly to SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

check code :

```
if(isset($_POST['submitSearch']))
{
    $_session['$search'] = $_POST['search'];  
    $all_post_query= "select * from files where recieved_by like '%$_SESSION[$search]%' or processed_by like  '% $_SESSION[$search]%' or   purpose like  '%$_SESSION[$search]%' or file_name like  '%$_SESSION[$search]%' order by date desc";
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fileprogramsysteeem");
    $all_post_run=mysqli_query($con,$all_post_query);
    $all_post=mysqli_num_rows( $all_post_run);
    $total_page=ceil($all_post/$total_num_page);
    $page_start_from=($page_id-1)*$total_num_page;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your problem is in the pagination itself. Your code takes $_POST parameter as search query, but when you click on pagination link, you create a new GET request and the search parameter is lost. You are saving the search parameter in session , so you need to alter your code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitSearch']) || $_SESSION['search'])
            {
                if($_POST['submitSearch']){
                    $_SESSION['search']=$_POST['search'];  
                }

                $all_post_query= "select * from files where recieved_by like '%". $_SESSION["search"]. "%' or processed_by like  '%".$_SESSION["search"]."%' or   purpose like  '%".$_SESSION["search"]."%' or file_name like  '%".$_SESSION["search"]."%' order by date desc";
                $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fileprogramsysteeem");
                $all_post_run=mysqli_query($con,$all_post_query);
                $all_post=mysqli_num_rows( $all_post_run);
                $total_page=ceil($all_post/$total_num_page);
                $page_start_from=($page_id-1)*$total_num_page;

             }
```

Also i've changed the way you create your session variable:

$_session["$search"]   ->  $_SESSION["search"]

Comment: Sir same output is coming as it coming before again,  after going second page it leaving  search filter

Comment: please post also the HTML of your search/results page including the pager - if you use the $_POST['submitSearch'] variable anywhere else in your code, this value will be empty once you navigate via pager

Comment: No Sir there is not use of $_POST[submitSearch'] anywhere  in this page

Comment: thank you sir , but could you please help me again , where i am doing this wrong

Comment: Try to echo the $_SESSION['search'] variable after you navigate through pagination - is it being set? Are you initiating the session with session_start() ?

Answer (score 0):

remove `white space` after `%`

`%$_SESSION["$search"]% //remove wite space` in your `query` and write `$_session to $_SESSION` so your query like below

```
"select * from files where recieved_by like '%$_SESSION["$search"]%' or processed_by like  '% $_session["$search"]%' or  purpose like  '%$_SESSION["$search"]%' or file_name like  '%$_SESSION["$search"]%' order by date desc";
```

Comment: First if you have use $_POST['submitSearch'] again in page yhen it will leave to  next post search .